# dynamic form not posting full array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm trying to give my users the ability to add multiple values, if needed. I using the following JS form:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
   if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
   }
   else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' value=''>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
   }
}
</script>
```

The following form:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<div id="dynamicInput">Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"></div>
Enter the POC's number<br>
<input type="button" value="Add another POC" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I fill in the first value as 123 and the second value as 124, once it posts to add.php, I only get the first value. I've confirmed the values are not posting (through print_r($_POST);) and through firebug.

```
Array ( [myInputs] => Array ( [0] => 123 )
```

Can anyone find why I'm losing the rest of the array?

Comment: are array inputs supported by all browsers?

Comment: you're missing the '/' from the input tag. you have `<input type='text' name='myInputs[]' value=''>` instead of `<input type='text' name='myInputs[]' value=''/>`

Comment: I ran this, and it works for me (in Chrome).

Comment: @NicolasBrown, I'm not sure, however, I know this script does work in Firefox and IE (as it's working on a live site as we speak). I literally copy and pasted this.

Comment: @Dylan it works for me too. I'm guessing it's a server or php issue then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the form handler in your site, because array element [Submit] => Submit is losted too. Check it on the single php-page. I think problem is not in this script or this form.

Comment: That is where I was starting to get concerned. Any suggestions on first places to look?

Comment: I've seemed to isolate this to the MAMP server that this is running on. Haven't found an explanation but overall, the code works (as others have stated).